# Solve $\cos(x)-\sin3x=\cos2x$

Tags: trigonometry

How do you solve this equation  $\cos(x)-\sin3x=\cos2x$?

I have tried to rewrite as follows:
$$\cos(2x)-\cos(x)=-\sin3x$$ 
$$=-2\sin(\frac{3}{2}x)\sin x=-3\sin x+4\sin^3x$$

Is it correct? Is it possible to proceed from here or I need to transform it differently?

Transform $\cos2x$ into $1-2\sin^2x$ is not useful here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it as
$$
\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}-\frac{e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}}{2i}=\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{2}
$$
that becomes
$$
e^{3ix}-e^{-3ix}+ie^{2ix}+ie^{-2ix}-ie^{ix}-ie^{-ix}=0
$$
or, setting $z=e^{ix}$,
$$
z^6-1+iz^5-iz^2-iz^4+iz=0
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$
(z^3-1)(z^3+1)+iz^2(z^3-1)-iz(z^3-1)=0
$$
This yields $z^3-1=0$ or
$$
z^3+iz^2-iz+1=0
$$
The last one can be factored as $(z+i)(z^2-i)=0$. Thus we get:

- from $z^3=1$, $e^{3ix}=e^{0+2ki\pi}$
- from $z+i=0$, $e^{ix}=e^{-i\pi/2+2ki\pi}$
- from $z^2-i$, $e^{2ix}=e^{i\pi/2+2ki\pi}$

Finally:

- $x=2k\pi/3$
- $x=-\pi/2+2k\pi$
- $x=\pi/4+k\pi$

Comment: Very nice way, even if not much simple but effective!

Comment: I think there is an error occured with the sign of $\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}$. If you move all to the left hand side, it must be $-\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}$

Comment: @JamesWarthington The right hand side is $\cos2x$. I used the equation as reported in the title.

Comment: My bad. It should be $\frac{e^{2ix}+e^{-2ix}}{2}$ on the RHS. If you move it to the LHS, it must be $-\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2}$

Comment: @JamesWarthington With a $+$, like in my formula.

Answer (score 2):

By [**sum to product formula**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) we have

- $\cos(x)-\cos2x=-2\sin(-x/2)\sin(3x/2)=2\sin(x/2)\sin(3x/2)$

and

- $\sin(3x)=2\sin(3x/2)\cos(3x/2)$

then

$$\cos(x)-\sin3x=\cos2x \iff 2\sin(x/2)\sin(3x/2)=2\sin(3x/2)\cos(3x/2)$$

therefore we have **two cases**

**1.** $\sin (3x/2)=0 \implies \frac32 x=k\pi \implies
    \color{red}{x=\frac23k\pi}$

otherwise

**2.** $\sin(x/2)=\cos(3x/2)$

which implies

- $\frac12 x=\frac{\pi}2-\frac32 x +2k\pi\implies \color{red}{x=\frac{\pi}4+k\pi}$
- $\frac12 x=\frac{\pi}2+\frac32 x +2k\pi\implies \color{red}{x=-\frac{\pi}2+2k\pi}$

Comment: Hint for the second part: $\sin y=\cos(\pi/2-y)$.

Comment: @egreg Yes I was just working on that, finally I've added also the second part using $\sin x=\cos (\pi/2 \pm x)$. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$\cos(x)-\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-3x)=\cos2x$$
and use the formula 
$$\cos a-\cos b=-2\sin(\dfrac{a+b}{2})\sin(\dfrac{a-b}{2})$$
for the left side. then
\begin{align}
2\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-2x)
&= \cos2x\\
&= \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-2x)\\
&= \sin2(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)\\
&= 2\sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{4}-x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
 $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-\sin^3(x)$$

$$\cos(2x)=1-\sin^2(x)$$
with my hint you will get

$$- \left( 1+2\,\cos \left( x \right)  \right)  \left( 2\,\sin \left( x
 \right) \cos \left( x \right) +\cos \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x
 \right) -1 \right) 
=0$$
The first factor is $$1+2\cos(x)=0$$
And in the second one use the substituion

$$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
Can you finish now?
It is the so-called Weierstrass substitution

Comment: I still cannot solve this equation using the above identities. (They are wrong so I have to correct them). Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Ok one moment please.

Answer (score 0):

Since, using the multiple angle formulae, $$\cos (x)-\sin (3 x)-\cos (2 x)=\sin ^3(x)+\sin ^2(x)-\cos ^2(x)+\cos (x)-3 \sin (x) \cos ^2(x)$$ use the tangent half angle substitution $t=\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$ to end with 
$$\frac{ t \left(t^5+3 t^4-2 t^3-10 t^2-3 t+3\right)}{\left(1+t^2\right)^3}=0$$ But the quintic polynomial can easily be factorized leading, for the numerator, to
$$t (t+1)(t^2-3)(t^2+2 t-1)=0$$